# xcode error: setenabled is unavailable on ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I am updating an app that was last updated about a year ago. I'm an amateur so usually all that I need to do is update the database and it builds fine and I send off to apple.

This time I'm getting a single fatal Semantic error (title of this question):

'setEnabled:' is unavailable: not available on iOS

It occurs 16 times in the Home.m file. Each time is slightly different, but this is a typical example:

```
[appDelegate.window setEnabled:NO];
```

Is there an easy fix for this?
Thank you.

Comment: `UIWindow` (nor any of its parent classes) have ever had an `enabled` property (or `setEnabled:` method).

Comment: What does that mean? Is it possibly a legacy from 6 years ago (when I originally commisioned the app)? Should I just delete those lines of code?